# Populate a generic collection at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I am trying to write a tool where I need to create and return object of a class given in a DLL using reflection. The DLL may contain many classes and class may have many variable including primitives, generics, collections and objects of the other class.

I am having particular trouble populating collections, because I do not know beforehand what kind of collection (whether a List, Dictionary, HashSet or anything else) is it going to be. I have written code to get the arguments of the collection, and code to create some random objects to insert in the collection; but I am stuck at the actual insertion process itself.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if (fieldType.IsGenericType)
{
    Type[] typeArgs = fieldType.GetGenericArguments(); // Get the arguments, for eg, List<String> will return String as argument
    object genericObj;

    /* Check if it has generic type definition or specific type definition then create the object */
    if (fieldType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
    {
        Type constructGeneric = fieldType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        genericObj = Activator.CreateInstance(constructGeneric);
    }
    else
    {
        genericObj = Activator.CreateInstance(fieldType);
    }
    //populate genericObj with 7 key-val pair --> in case of List<String> I want to populate the List with 7 Strings, in case of Dictionary<int,string> I want 7 <int, string> pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        Object[] oArr = new Object[typeArgs.Length];
        int ctr = 0;
        foreach (Type ta in typeArgs)
        {
            if (ta.IsPrimitive || Type.GetTypeCode(ta) == TypeCode.String)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                var buffer = new byte[sizeof(Int64)];
                rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
                switch (Type.GetTypeCode(ta))
                {
                    case TypeCode.Boolean:
                        oArr[ctr] = (rnd.Next(100) % 2 == 0);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Byte:
                        oArr[ctr] = buffer[0];
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.SByte:
                        oArr[ctr] = (sbyte)buffer[0];
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Char:
                        oArr[ctr] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * rnd.NextDouble() + 65));
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        oArr[ctr] = NextDecimal(rnd);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                        oArr[ctr] = rnd.NextDouble() * rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                        var buf = new byte[sizeof(Single)];
                        rnd.NextBytes(buf);
                        oArr[ctr] = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, 0);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                        oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.UInt32:
                        oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue) + (rnd.Next(100) % 2) * rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                        oArr[ctr] = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.UInt64:
                        oArr[ctr] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Int16:
                        oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int16.MaxValue);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.UInt16:
                        oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int16.MaxValue) + (rnd.Next(100) % 2) * rnd.Next(Int16.MaxValue);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.String:
                        oArr[ctr] = RandomString(rnd.Next(100));
                        break;
                    default:
                        oArr[ctr] = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                oArr[ctr] = getInstance(dllFile, ta.Name);
            }
            ctr++;
            if(genericObj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().ToString() == "ICollection") {
                // This is where I am stuck -- HOW TO INSERT??
            }
        }
    }
    //setvalue
    f.SetValue(obj, genericObj);
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess you could check if the type derives from `IList`, `IDictionary`, `HashSet` and so on, use reflection to pull out the appropriate `Add` method and go to town. (`IDictionary` will be interesting as you'll have to provide a key _and_ value)

Answer (score 0):

like any other collection.. call the `Add` method on the object (or perhaps it is the Add method of the Items proeprty)

Comment: The problem is that `Add` method does not even appear in the suggestion. I guess I need to specify what kind of `Collection` am I referring it to.

Comment: `genericObj.GetType().GetMEthod('Add').Invoke(new object[] {oArr[ctr]});`  or something similar.  If you are still stuck in a little bit let us know and someone will fire up VS and get you a working sample.